# Necessary condition for $X^{\prime}AX$ to be inversible

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be the positive definite matrix. I used the inverse of $X^{\prime}AX$ somewhere in my calculations, for some real-valued matrix $X$, and I set the assumption that $X^{\prime}AX$ is a nonsingular matrix. I also argue that a sufficient condition is that $X$ is a full rank matrix.

I would like to know if this condition is also necessary; that is, $X^{\prime}AX$ is a nonsingular matrix if and only if $X$ is a full rank matrix.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary, because $\operatorname{rank}(X^TAX)=\operatorname{rank}\left((A^{1/2}X)^T(A^{1/2}X)\right)=\operatorname{rank}(A^{1/2}X)=\operatorname{rank}(X)$.

Comment: You systematically assume that A is symmetric. What if A is not symmetric?

Comment: Real positive definite matrices by definition are symmetric.

Comment: Why? counter-example: $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$?. For any $x \in R^2$ and $x \ne 0$, $x^{\prime}A x > 0$.

Comment: Do you see the counter-example? It is a classical example of nonsymmetric positive definite matrix.

Comment: What I am saying is that there is no such thing as a “(real) non-symmetric positive definite matrix”. We don't speak of the definiteness of a real matrix when it is not symmetric.